# Testing basic directive with jasmine not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jsp, jasmine

We use a directive called 'ngEnter' that can be found online in several places (it's actually a really silly directive, but I'm learning how to use Jasmine and this one had a test written for it.) I'm pretty sure I have all of the files set up correctly. The source files for SpecRunner.html and the spec files are in the right places, same for karma.conf.js. When I run the specrunner and place breakpoints, all of the variables are correct, but for some reason the compiled HTML doesn't call the directive. I see that our app has the directive loading first, I even put console logs to make sure the directive was loading first and then the spec compiles second.

The code looks like this:

**Spec**

```
describe('Directive: ngEnter', function () {

/**
* load the directive's module
*/
beforeEach(module(app));

var element,
scope;

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {

  scope = $rootScope;
  scope.mockFunction = function(){};
  compileDirective();

}));

/**
* Compile the directive into HTML
*/
function compileDirective(){
  element = angular.element('<input type="text" data-ng-enter="mockFunction()"/>');
  inject(function($compile){
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
  });
  scope.$apply();
}

it('should call the mock function upon pressing enter', function () {
  spyOn(scope, 'mockFunction');

  var e = jQuery.Event('keypress');
  e.which = 13;
  e.keyCode = 13;
  element.trigger(e);
  expect(scope.mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**js**

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
            });

            event.preventDefault();
          }
      });
  };
});
```

What can I do to get this test to work? I have a feeling that it has to do with our web application running on servlets, but if that's the case, why can I still see the module and the spec? Everything else appears to be working. Here's a pic of the folder set-up.

[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGlmJ.png)